# Cosmos DB: How to retry failures with TransactionalBatch

Tags: azure, transactions, azure-cosmosdb, transient-failure

I have a few stored procedures in `Cosmos DB` that I'd like to convert to .NET transactions. Recently, I saw this post https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-transactionalbatch-in-the-net-sdk/ that goes over transaction support. I was also able to test it, and it seems to be working fine.

I know that .NET has added built-in retry logic into many of its supported packages. Does `TransactionalBatch` have any built-in retry policy? What is the recommended approach to retrying any failures? The post above is looking at `IsSuccessStatusCode`. Should we retry once the status is fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does TransactionalBatch have any built-in retry policy?

For now, it does not support built-in retry policy.

> What is the recommended approach to retrying any failures?

TransactionalBatch describes a group of point operations that need to either succeed or fail.**If any operation fails, the entire transaction is rolled back**.

Because the failed status code will be 424 and 409, so we could not use [`RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.retryoptions.maxretryattemptsonthrottledrequests?view=azure-dotnet).

So, you could use `for (int i = 0; i < MaxRetries; i++){}` to perform the retry logic.